# cocos2d-x: How to specify a pixel format for a specific Texture2D

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've set my app to use the RGBA4444 pixel format by default for its Texture2D objects.

`Texture2D::setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat(Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA4444);`

This works great -- it has cut my memory footprint in half and 16 bit still looks fine for most images.  However, some images are a bit messed up... namely those that are primarily in one colour, such as a particular grassy background texture which uses quite a large number of green shades.  It looks absolutely horrible in anything less than 32 bit, and I'd rather not have to create a texture that looks nicer when 16 bit'ified.

[image: 32 bit on the left, 16 bit on the right]

The best solution for me would be to be able to set the sprite to use RGBA8888 as an exception. After all, 'setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat()' implies that it can be specified otherwise, right? But I have been as-yet unable to find out how.

Can it be done?

Comment: you can change the texture format right before loading this specific texture, then immideately afterwards change it back to 4444

Comment: That does work.  It means I can't add the image to the texture cache asynchronously though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to change the default format before loading and set it back again afterwards.  This is how I did it:

```
Texture2D::PixelFormat defaultFormat = Texture2D::getDefaultAlphaPixelFormat();
Texture2D::setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat(Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888);

// Load RGBA8888 textures here
TextureCache::getInstance()->addImage(IMAGE_BACKGROUND_GRASS);

Texture2D::setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat(defaultFormat);
```

I think this is about as good as it gets, thanks LearnCocos2D. :)